# What is the best way to play video file in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, multimedia

I need to play video file (using installed codecs) and get some file info (such as frame rate and length).

Comment: You should accept the answer from Serge if you choose the VideoLab components.

Comment: Hm, I think i should accept both of answers (because i dont know which components are better) but i cant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Mitov's [VideoLab](http://www.mitov.com/html/videolab.html)

**Updated**:
I have previously installed Mitov's "Labs" version 3.9 on Delphi 2009 without problems. Check that you are using the correct [link](http://www.mitov.com/html/start_download_videolab_delphi.html) and contact the author if there are problems for Delphi 2010.

Comment: Seems that these components are just what i need, but i cant install them. After installation there are no new components and the examples do not work. I use Delphi 2010

Comment: These components are GOOD. I use them A LOT, in Delphi 2010. The examples all work too.  There must be something strange going on with your installation. What exactly doesn't work in the examples? Do they compile?  Do you have DirectX installed? (Try running DxDiag from the command prompt.)

Contact Boian by email and he'll get you going.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [DSPack](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dspack/). It is well tested and used and I have used it in a couple of projects. Works very well. It also has a wide range of features.

The updated version for Delphi 2010 can be [downloaded here](http://tib.s.songbeamer.eu/downloads/DSPack.zip).

Oh and its free.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need information on the video without actually having a need to display it, you can get all the information you listed using [MediaInfo](https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo). MediaInfo is free and has headers for multiple languages, including Delphi.